# Failing to migrate table from ID to UUID in Rails due to dependency

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am looking to migrate two table from using ID to using UUID. 
I built the following migration:

```
class MajorChangeToUuid < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    add_column :messages, :uuid, :uuid, default: 
    "gen_random_uuid()", null: false
    change_table :messages, force: :cascade do |t|
      t.remove :id
      t.rename :uuid, "id"
    end

    execute "ALTER TABLE messages ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);"

    add_column :comments, :uuid, :uuid, default: 
    "gen_random_uuid()", null: false
    change_table :comments do |t|
      t.remove :id
      t.rename :uuid, "id"
    end
    execute "ALTER TABLE comments ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);
  end
end
```

But when i run the rake db:migrate, I get the following error:

```
PG::DependentObjectsStillExist: ERROR:  cannot drop column id of table messages because other objects depend on it
DETAIL:  constraint fk_rails_6c909d51ab on table comments depends on column id of table messages
HINT:  Use DROP ... CASCADE to drop the dependent objects too.
: ALTER TABLE "messages" DROP "id"
```

I see that I need to use `:cascade`, but not sure where it should go. Can someone help please?
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to remove the reference to messages from the comments table before dropping id from messages.

You'll need to update the foreign key to be the new uuid from messages.

Comment: Hey, thank you for the guidance. How do I remove the reference to messages from the comments table (in the model ?). And to update the foreign key as well? (sorry not familiar with the procedure here.

Comment: 1. Add new uuid column to messages
2. Add message_uuid column to comments
3. execute 'UPDATE comments SET message_uuid = (SELECT uuid FROM messages WHERE id = message_id)'
4. Remove message_id from comments
5. Remove id from messages
6. Rename uuid to id on messages
7. Rename message_uuid to message_id on comments
8. Add foreign key from comments.message_id to messages.id

Something like that should get it done

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [remove_foreign_key](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements/remove_foreign_key) method, I have read that you need to remove the old and re-add the new key.

A new migration which could run before yours could look like:

```
class UpdateForeignKey < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    # remove the old foreign_key
    remove_foreign_key :posts, :users

    # add the new foreign_key
    add_foreign_key :posts, :users, on_delete: :cascade
  end
end
```

Sorry, for not being specific about your use case. I hope this helps anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you guys for the answers,  they put me in the right direction. I ended up doing:

```
add_column :messages, :uuid, :uuid, default: "gen_random_uuid()", null: false
add_column :comments, :message_uuid, :uuid, default: "gen_random_uuid()", null: false
execute "UPDATE comments SET message_uuid = (SELECT uuid FROM messages WHERE id = message_id)"
remove_column :comments, :message_id
change_table :messages do |t|
  t.remove :id
  t.rename :uuid, "id"
end
execute "ALTER TABLE messages ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);"
rename_column :comments, :message_uuid, "message_id"
add_foreign_key :comments, :messages, on_delete: :cascade
add_column :comments, :uuid, :uuid, default: "gen_random_uuid()", null: false
change_table :comments do |t|
  t.remove :id
  t.rename :uuid, "id"
end
```

The migration went through smoothly, now checking if there is no issue on the actual app. Thanks again!